# How do I set up my Gmail profile picture so others can see it, and not just me?

Tags: gmail, google-account

I set a profile picture, but it only shows up for me, not to others on any emails I've sent to them. I can't get a Google+ account because I'm using my school email. So, is there a way to set it so that others who I email can see it when I email them, and not just me? Even though I can't get a Google+ account? Or is there no way for that to happen?

Answer (score 1):

For this you don't need to have Google Plus account. You can set Gmail profile picture and picture's visibility. From Gmail Help:

> **Change your picture**
>
> 1. Open Gmail.
> 2. In the top right, click Settings Settings (gear icon).
> 3. Click **Settings**.
> 4. In the "My Picture" section, click **Change picture**.
> 5. Select or upload a new picture.
> 6. Select the portion of the photo you want to show.
> 7. Click **Apply changes**.
>
> **Change your picture's visibility**
>
> 1. Using a browser, open Gmail.
> 2. In the top right, click Settings Settings (gear icon).
> 3. Click **Settings**.
> 4. In the "My Picture" section, select a visibility option.
>
> **Visible to everyone:** Anyone who you email, or who emails you, can see your picture.
>
> **Visible only to people I can chat with:** Only people you've given permission to chat with you or see when you're online can see your picture.